# GoogleMaps on Android showing grey squares

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I have a Eclipse Android project of my colleague in which development i need to continue. When I install .apk file from bin directory of his project, everything is going fine, Google Maps are working. But when I import project into Eclipse and then use my .apk file generated by imported project, google maps are not working. On screen are little grey squares instead of Google Maps. May the problem be in API key? I´m using key which has been generated by colleague on his computer.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Are you using googlemap apiv1 or apiv2

Comment: the key wont's match as your debug.keystore is not the same as his u ll have 2 generate a new 1

Comment: Yes it is the wrong key. Not having an accepted key will make the google maps all gray and stuff.

Comment: Did you set custom keystore path after import from Window->Preferences->Android->Build.

Comment: If you're using a live API key in the emulator you will see grey tiles. Exporting a signed version of the application and loading that on your device should let you see the tiles (provided you're using the right keys etc)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to either be using your colleagues debug key or perhaps a deploy key he has created. You either have two options.

1. Sign up for API access using your own debug key
2. Get his debug key and override your own debug key

Answer (score 0):

On every computer,that you work on your Google map application you have to generate your own `SHA1` key
for this specific machine and register it via the Google API Console together with you package name of the application.

You can check this blog post I wrote on doing just that:

[Get your Google Map API V2 key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)